# Getting Frequent Time out

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlsession

I am Getting Frequent Timeout errors (not always but some times)although the timeout is set 500 .Chekd the same on postman too Two things one in postman the connection is always keep alive and second  one is "The request timed out" coming randomly not always .BUt it just happen as soon as screen opened as i have called the webservice in ViewDidload so it has to at-least wait a bit .before throwing the error

what might be the possible cause for this

Below is my implementation for request

```
+(void)placeRequest:(NSString *)action parametersString:(NSString*)postDataStr withHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))ourBlock {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", IOS_BASE_URL, action];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",@"Connection":@"keep-alive",                              @"cache-control": @"no-cache"};
    NSString *parmetersToPost=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",postDataStr,[AppDelegate UserWebCommeParmeters] ];
    NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[parmetersToPost   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *logString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here the Url is : \n\n\n\n %@ \n\n\n\n\nAction Used is :========>  %@ \n\n\n\n\n and the Parmeter posted are :=============> %@",IOS_BASE_URL,action,parmetersToPost];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData                                                     timeoutInterval:500.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"All header Sent are %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:ourBlock] resume];
}
```

Calling this method as below in viewdidload

```
 [HttpRequest placeRequest:@"check_value" parametersString:postData  withHandler:^(NSData *receivedData, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *err){

}];
```

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://cms.xa.com/apps/xa/ax/myFuntion,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://cms.xa.com/apps/xa/ax/myFuntion,
>   **NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,**
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x16587760 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}

Comment: did you check in postman for this issue ?

Comment: Yes ..Two things one in postman the connection is always keep alive and second  one is "The request timed out" coming randomly not always .BUt it just happen as soon as screen opened as called the webservice in ViewDidload so it has to at-least wait a bit .berfore throwing the error

Comment: How you call method in viewdidload ? Did you use performselector with some delay to call webservice ?

Comment: Nope no performselector ,Just calling the class method as     [HttpRequest placeRequest:@"apply_leave" parametersString:postData  withHandler:^(NSData *receivedData, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *err){}];

Comment: So call in into performselector with some delay like 0.3-0.7 sec and try it